# gtk_widget_add_tick_callback() and gtk_main_iteration()

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, gtkmm3

I have two GTK windows

1. Normal (main) window that runs animation, draws stuff in callback registered  by `gtk_widget_add_tick_callback()`.
2. At some point secondary window is created that runs modal loop:

   ```
   void show_modal() 
   {
      GtkWindow* gw = gtkwindow(this);

      if( parent() )
        gtk_window_set_transient_for(gw, gtkwindow( parent() ));


      gtk_widget_show(GTK_WIDGET(gw));
      gtk_window_set_modal(gw,TRUE);
      gtk_window_set_keep_above(gw,TRUE);
      this->update_window_state(gool::WINDOW_SHOWN);

      while( this->is_valid_window() )
      {
         if(this->_window_state == WINDOW_HIDDEN) break;
         if(this->_window_state == WINDOW_STATE_NA) break;
         gtk_main_iteration(); // gtk_main_iteration_do(true);
      }
   }
   ```

Problem: Animation in main window works fine until `show_modal()` is invoked. It appears as `gtk_main_iteration();` blocks ticks added by `gtk_widget_add_tick_callback()` function. As soon as I close secondary window  and so `while() {gtk_main_iteration();}` loop exits then animations in main window start running again.

Any idea of how to make "animation friendly" modal loops in GTK?

UPDATE: it appears as `gtk_main_iteration();` blocks not only ticks but any updates of any windows other than "current" - they are simply frozen. What is the reasoning of such GTK behavior?

UPDATE #2:

`gtk_dialog_run();` behaves exactly as `gtk_main_iteration();` - locks any updates on any window in process other than active window.

Comment: How is this secondary window created and `show_modal` invoked? In `gtk_widget_add_tick_callback`? This loop will then prevent callback from returning.

Comment: That loop can be invoked on other UI events, e.g. on [mouse] button release event.

"This loop will then prevent callback from returning" - exactly!  So is the question:  "how to make "animation friendly" modal loops in GTK? " and "how to define modal loop without locking updates of background windows?"

Comment: Does it actually block the other loop or does it only prevent from updating the UI? Try adding a print statement in your tick callback.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be by definition: [link](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html#gtk-main-iteration)

> `gboolean gtk_main_iteration (void);`
>   Runs a single iteration of the mainloop. If no events are waiting to be processed GTK+ **will block** until the next event is noticed. If you don’t want to block look at `gtk_main_iteration_do()` or check if any events are pending with `gtk_events_pending()` first.

The explanation suggests to use `gtk_main_iteration_do(FALSE)` if you don't want blocking:

> `gboolean gtk_main_iteration_do (gboolean blocking);` 
>   Runs a single iteration of the mainloop. If no events are available either return or block depending on the value of `blocking`:
>   `TRUE` if you want GTK+ to block if no events are pending

As for `gtk_dialog_run`: it also blocks *by design* [link](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDialog.html#gtk-dialog-run)

> `gint gtk_dialog_run (GtkDialog *dialog);`
>   **Blocks** in a recursive main loop until the dialog either emits the “response” signal, or is destroyed.[...]

I read about people solving this using multiple threads: handle the GUI in the main thread and do background work in another one. There's an article about it [here](https://www.cairographics.org/threaded_animation_with_cairo/) that might be useful.

Comment: That's the nature of modal loops on all UI platforms - to block current execution by showing window with the question and running "message pump" loop until it gets closed. Like here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/348/Implementing-Modal-Message-Loops

On Windows and Mac that works just fine. It is just on GTK `gtk_main_iteration_do(/*does not matter what*/)` does not dispatch messages to any other windows except the active one. For unknown reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `show_modal` is called from a callback or other activity in main context. You could try adding your modal window into main context using [invoke](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/2.52/classGlib_1_1MainContext.html#ab51154582ff342993ff27fa0024ab38f) or [signal_idle](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/2.52/classGlib_1_1SignalIdle.html#ac8befbaf1d10a17d1f3f75143e967a3f).

This way execution of `show_modal` will end.

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    auto Application = Gtk::Application::create();
    Gtk::Window window;
    Gtk::Window* window2;
    Gtk::Button button;
    window.add(button);

    //I hope timeout behaves similar to ticks. I have no idea how animations in GTK work
    int i=0;
    Glib::MainContext::get_default()->signal_timeout().connect([&]()->bool{
            button.set_label(std::to_string(i++));
            return true;
        }, 1000);

    button.signal_clicked().connect([&]{
            Glib::MainContext::get_default()->invoke([&]()->bool{
                    window2 = new Gtk::Window;
                    window2->set_modal(true);
                    window2->set_keep_above(true);
                    window2->signal_delete_event().connect([&](GdkEventAny* any_event)->bool{
                            delete window2;
                            return false;
                        });
                    window2->show_all();
                    return false;
                });
        });

    window.show_all();

    return Application->run(window);
}
```

Comment: That's not a modal dialog but rather modeless.  And there is no problem with such windows/dialogs in GTK.

This `window->show_modal()` means that next line after it will be executed only after user will close the dialog. Such show_modal() is implemented roughly as this:   `window->show(); run_message_pump_until_hidden(window);` and correct implementation of that hypothetical `run_message_pump_until_hidden()` is the question.

Comment: I'm guessing that running `show_modal` in a callback blocks redrawing of animation. `gtk_main_iteration_do` iterates the loop, but redraw is only queued, not executed. Could you post some code with your animation and where you are calling `show_modal`? (io watch, button click, idle?)